# MySQLdb library issue on cpanel based shared hosting

Tags: python, mysql, cpanel, mysql-python

I am trying to run python script and wish to connect python to the mysql on my cpanel based shard hosting.
When i type the following in `test.py` inside `cgi-bin` folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 
import MySQLdb
```

I get an import error. This, to what i assume, that the MySQLdb library is not installed on the hosting server.  What is the solution to this issue? How do i manually install this library? Can i externally link to this library?

Comment: Refer to your hosting provider policy on installing libraries. They may take requests for it through support tickets.

Comment: yes, I could contact the service provider and the library was installed on request...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

honestly you will need MySQLdb for any python mysql code. Better consult with your web host.

If you can access to site-packages directory  `~/lib/python2.7/site-packages,` then build/install will work

Check if mysqldb installed or not using

```
#!/usr/bin/python

module_name = 'MySQLdb'

try:
    __import__(module_name)
    print 'installed'
except ImportError:
    print 'not installed'
```